# Numpy: create new array by combining subsets of previous array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a binary sparse CSR array. I would like to create a new array by combining columns from this original array. That is, I have a list of "column groups": [[1,10,3], [5,54,202], [12,199], [5], ...]

For each of these "column groups" I want to combine columns from the original array with an OR operation (np.max works for this) and add the combined column to a new matrix.

My current solution is to use hstack but it's quite slow:

```
for cg in column_groups:
    tmp = np.max(data_orig[:,cg].toarray(), axis=1, keepdims=True)
    data = np.hstack((data, tmp))
```

Comment: By sparse, do you mean that there are few elements being one in your array, or is it stored as a sparse structure using scipy.sparse?

Comment: @JohanL it's stored as a scipy sparse CSR matrix currently

Comment: I suspect that the `csr` column indexing is the slow step.  Collecting `tmp` via `hstack` is slower than list append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you are basically selecting the `max` column at each iteration. So, we can select all columns and then use [`np.maximum.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) to have "intervaled-maximum" columns and hence give us a vectorized solution, like so -

```
def grouped_max(data_orig, column_groups):
    cols = np.hstack((column_groups))
    clens = np.hstack((0,np.cumsum(map(len,column_groups))[:-1]))
    all_data = data_orig[:,cols].toarray()
    return np.maximum.reduceat(all_data, clens,axis=1)
```

For python 3.x version, we need to compute `clens`, like so -

```
clens = np.hstack((0,np.cumsum(list(map(len,column_groups)))[:-1]))
```

Since, the loopy version is iterating along groups, this vectorized solution would show its benefits when working with a large number of groups.

Sample run -

```
In [303]: # Setup sample csr matrix
     ...: a = np.random.randint(0,3,(12,28))
     ...: data_orig = sparse.csr_matrix(a)
     ...: 
     ...: # Random column IDs
     ...: column_groups = [[1,10,3], [5,14],[2]]
     ...: 
     ...: data = np.empty((12,0),dtype=int)
     ...: for cg in column_groups:
     ...:     tmp = np.max(data_orig[:,cg].toarray(), axis=1, keepdims=True)
     ...:     data = np.hstack((data, tmp))
     ...:     

In [304]: out = grouped_max(data_orig, column_groups)

In [305]: # Verify results between original and propsed ones
     ...: print np.allclose(out, data)
True
```

Comment: I made a mistake in the original post by including the `enumerate` and have removed it. the idea is just to grab a set of columns (`cg` is a list of column numbers), combine them, then add them to the new array.

Comment: A follow up. Is there any way to adapt this solution so that it's not necessary to convert to a dense array?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue, I guess, is that hstack is building a new matrix - copying a lot of data - in every iteration.

I haven't worked with sparse matrices, so I may be out of line, but as far as I can understand from the documentation it is possible to slice them as normal numpy arrays. In that case, it would be a good idea to pre-allocate the array and the just add the results column by column:

```
rows = data_orig.shape[0]
cols = len(column_groups)
data = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((rows, cols))
for cg in enumerate(column_groups):
    tmp = np.max(data_orig[:,cg[1]].toarray(), axis=1, keepdims=True)
    data[:, cg[0]] = tmp
```

Comment: Yes, accidentally left the enumerate in, just removed it.

Comment: Well, it is needed with the solution I just proposed (if it works). ;-)

Comment: I see, you propose to construct it first. But doesn't reassigning a column take just as long as hstack? I guess I'll have to test it.

Comment: It could be that it takes almost the same time for sparse arrays. For full sized arrays there is a vast difference.

Comment: By the way, is `data`sparse in your initial solution? Is it possible to use np.hstack also on a sparse matrix? You don't need to do scipy.sparse.hstack?

Comment: No, the process converts it to dense. I didn't even know about sparse stacking, maybe that'll be faster as well.

Comment: OK, if you define data as a regular dense matrix (instead of sparse, as I have tried to make it) by doing `data = np.empty((rows, cols))` then my solution should be substantially quicker than yours.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [412]: data_orig=sparse.random(10,300,.2,'csr')
In [413]: data_orig = (data_orig>.5).astype(int)
In [414]: cg = [[1,10,3], [5,54,202], [12,199], [5]]
In [420]: data_orig
Out[420]: 
<10x300 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
   with 299 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

For repeated joining it is better to append to a list, and stack once:

```
def test1(data_orig, cg):
    data = []
    for g in cg:
        temp=np.max(data_orig[:,g].A, axis=1,keepdims=True)
        data.append(temp)
    return np.hstack(data)

In [429]: test1(data_orig, cg)
Out[429]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

I could convert the sparse matrix to a dense one, and get the same result

```
In [431]: dataM=data_orig.todense()
In [432]: test1(dataM, cg)
```

I could have uses `data_orig.A` but then I'd have to omit the `.A` in the function.

```
In [433]: timeit test1(data_orig, cg)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.52 ms per loop
In [434]: timeit test1(dataM, cg)
10000 loops, best of 3: 118 µs per loop
```

These timings confirm my guess that the sparse column indexing is relatively slow.

With Divakar's `reduceat` version:

```
In [451]: timeit grouped_max(data_orig, cg)
1000 loops, best of 3: 706 µs per loop
In [452]: timeit grouped_max(dataM, cg)
10000 loops, best of 3: 90.3 µs per loop
```

With my own Py3 adaption (differences are just stylistic):

```
def grouped_max(data_orig, column_groups):
    cols = np.hstack((column_groups))
    clens = np.hstack((0,np.cumsum([len(i) for i in cg])[:-1]))
    all_data = data_orig[:,cols].A
    return np.maximum.reduceat(all_data, clens,axis=1)
```

The speed up for the sparse matrix is significant.  Evidently one larger column selection is faster than many smaller ones.  The speed up for the dense matrix isn't so significant.

Sparse matrix column select like this is actually performed with matrix multiplication.  It constructs another sparse matrix with 1s for the desired columns, and performs a `dot` product.  Row/column sum is also performed with a matrix product.

Here's a pure sparse version:

```
def test2(data_orig, cg):
    data = []
    for g in cg:
        temp=data_orig[:,g].max(axis=1)
        data.append(temp)          # alt append(temp.A)
    return sparse.hstack(data)     #      np.hstack

In [465]: timeit test2(data_orig, cg).A
100 loops, best of 3: 3.21 ms per loop  (2.99 with np.hstack)
```

Comment: Is `.A` is faster than `.toarray()`?

Comment: `.A` is the same thing, just cuter. (like `.T`).

Comment: Well then I am already covering for Py3 version of my vectorized solution in my post. I don't see the point of another Py3 version with the minor replacement of how `clens` is created with a loop comprehension, which won't affect the timings in any big way and as you said `.A` is just another way to put `.toarray()`.

Comment: When I first copied your function I didn't notice the PY3 adaptation.  The differences are just stylistic.